# Serial to ethernet cable: how to connect to device

Tags: switch, hp, ethernet, serial

How can I use a serial to ethernet cable to connect to a device: in my case a
Hp ProCurve AP?

A serial to USB or serial to serial would have been great but I found this serial
to ethernet cable from a Cisco router lying around and I though that I might use it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That cable is not a serial to Ethernet cable.  It is a female DB-9 to 8P8C plug serial cable.  Cisco uses 8P8C connectors that are the same as copper Ethernet for console access to their equipment.  That cable would normally go from 9pin serial on your computer to the router console which is also serial.  I'm guessing since you thought it was serial to Ethernet your HP kit has a male 9pin connector on it?  If so you will need a 9pin null modem cable with female 9pin connectors on both ends.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. You are right, I looked carefully and its a 8P8C serial not ethernet.

Comment: Can I just use a USB to female serial ?

Comment: Most USB -> Serial adapters will be male on the DB9 connector since they are designed to present a DTE signal to a DCE device (modem, etc).  It is most likely if your AP has a male DB9 it is also DTE in which case you need an adapter or cable that reverses Tx and Rx pins as "null modem"

Answer (score 0):

The cable needs to be a DB-9 female-to-female serial cable.

In your terminal emulator, such as HyperTerminal, use the following settings:

```
Baud rate (or bits per second): 9600
Data bits: 8
Parity: None
Stop bits: 1
Flow Control: None
```

Comment: Thank you Cold T. I find USB to serial easier but I don't know of there is USB to female ?